# Field Resolver to resolve array of Comments

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I have a Post model that contains an array of Comments. I am trying to use field-resolver to return a list of comments which I can query in my graphql playground. I am able to successfully resolve post - user however, I am unable to resolve post - comments. Can someone help me on this? Thanks

```
  Query: {
    //todo Using GraphQL Field Resolvers
    getPosts: combineResolvers(isAuthenticated, async (_, __, { Post }) => {
      const posts = await Post.find({});

      return posts;
    }),
  },
  Post: {
     comments: async (parent, input, { Comment }) => {
       console.log("parent", parent, input);
     },
    user: async (parent, __, { User }) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(parent.user);
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can work. If anyone has suggestion to make it better, welcome to share. Hope this answer will be able to help someone. Thanks

```
  Post: {
    comments: async (parent, __, { Post, Comment }) => {
      console.log("parent", parent);
      return parent.comments.map(async (c) => {
        return Comment.findById(c);
      });
    },
    user: async (parent, __, { User }) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(parent.user);
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      }
    },
  },
  Comment: {
    user: async (parent, __, { User }) => {
      console.log("parent ", parent);
      const user = await User.findById(parent.user);
      return user;
    },
  },
```